# How to plot a graph vertically in java?

Tags: java, plot, graph, graphics

I have to do a program that plot data vertically in java but I don't know what library to use to accomplish that. The datetime axis have to work vertically and the value of the varibles horizontally, also the graph can have multiples variables but with the datetime axis shared. The software will also have to have a line that says the value of all the variables. The following image is an example of what I want to do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating this graph as an output image? or as part of the UI of a larger interactive program? There are lots of options available for 3rd party libraries but I would just draw it myself if I were tasked with this. Would be pretty straightforward to mock up even in swing if you want to generate it and show it without exporting as an image.

[simple example](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSpring2007/cs313/lectures/graph.html)

Comment: No, this graph isn't an output image, It is part of the program UI

Comment: What are you using for your UI? Swing? Or another option.

Comment: I am not using anything at the moment, I am investigating first which is the best option to do it

Comment: Post updated with link to an example in swing and AWT. It’s quite old but should give you an idea how easy it would be to create your graph in a swing panel